# Check if "the parameter named by the value of x" is set

Tags: zsh

I am currently using a piece of code like this:

```
if (( $( eval "echo \${+$foo}" ) )); then
  ./my-prog
fi
```

Is there a more elegant or concise way to express this? Originally I tried

```
if (( ${+${(P)foo}} )); then
  ./my-prog
fi
```

but that raised the "bad substitution" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the `-v` operator, which precludes the need for indirect parameter expansion:

```
if [[ -v $foo ]]; then
  ./my-prog
fi
```

This is documented in `man zshmisc`, in the CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section.

Comment: Thanks, this happens to be better for the case I had in mind anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`(P)` and `+` can be used in the same parameter expansion, if you use them in the right order:

```
if (( ${(P)+foo} )); then
  ./my-prog
fi
```